# I deleted my Minecraft resource pack folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I deleted my Minecraft resource pack folder, how do I get it back?

I'm using a Mac and Minecraft version 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Resource pack as in your texturepack folder?

Have you tried going into your game, going to options, Texture Packs, and clicking Open Folder? That is one sure way to get it to work. Otherwise, go into your `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` and make a new folder called `resourcepacks`.

Or one thing you can do is this.

- Open the Launcher
- Go down to `Edit Profile`
- Click `Versions`
- Click `1.7.10`
- Click Update and then launch the game.

What this should do is put back any folders that were deleted or are missing. Afterwards, repeat the steps above, but change the `1.7.10` to `1.8` and you should be good to go. If you have any other problems, I will be willing to help you.

Comment: If nothing else, creating a folder called `resourcepacks` in your game folder should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply recreate the folder yourself in the game directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks
```